# Trying to find an IDE that support Groovy for Linux

Tags: linux, groovy, ide

As the Title states I'm having a hard time finding an IDE that supports Groovy for linux, I can't stand programming without color coding anymore.

Comment: Syntax highlighting != IDE.

Comment: How hard did you look? [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org), [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [GGTS](http://grails.org/products/ggts) are all full IDEs that work on Linux. And if you're just after syntax highlighting, there's [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) and many others...

Answer (score 3):

Use [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It has comprehensive Groovy support, runs on linux and is generally an awesome IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use IntelliJ IDEA, it supports multiple languages and runs well on Linux

click to see the introduction

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans supports Groovy and runs on Linux: https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse based Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) also runs on Linux.
http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts